# Show that $f=cg$ for some scalar $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is in connection with this one: [Show that $\langle v,w\rangle _1=c\langle v,w\rangle _2$ for some scalar $c$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2790305/562417).

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $f,g:V\to F$ such that $\ker f =\ker g$. Show that $f=cg$ for some scalar $c$.

If $f\equiv 0\implies g\equiv 0$, take $c=1$ we are done.

If $f\neq 0$ then $f(v_0)\neq 0\implies g(v_0)\neq 0$.

How can I prove $f=cg$ from here?

Comment: The question and answer/s to which you have provided the link answer your question. If not, can you explain what is the difficulty that you have?

Comment: @AnyAD:  In fact the questions are substantially different, though similar, since no inner products are introduced here.  Thus, this question generalizes the other one.  Indeed, there are plenty of vector spaces which are not self-dual, so representing functionals by inner products is not always feasible.  Cheers!

Comment: @Robert Lewis Thank you for that, I assumed incirrectly that this was an inner product space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's see . . . a smallish ***lemma*** might kick this off:

***Smallish Lemma:*** Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$, and let

$\lambda:V \to F \tag 1$

be linear over $F$; if $\lambda \ne 0$, then

***a.)***  There exists $w \in V$ with

$\lambda(w) = 1; \tag 2$

***b.)***  For any $v \in V$,

$v = aw + y, \; a = \lambda(v) \in F, \; y \in \ker \lambda; \tag 3$

***c.)*** $a$ and $y$ are unique.

***Proof of Smallish Lemma:***  For ***(a)***, since $\lambda \ne 0$, there is some $x \in V$ with

$\lambda(x) \ne 0; \tag 4$

set

$w = (\lambda(x))^{-1} x; \tag 5$

then

$\lambda(w) = \lambda( (\lambda(x))^{-1} x) =  (\lambda(x))^{-1} \lambda(x) = 1; \tag 6$

For ***(b)***:  if $v \in V$, set $a = \lambda(v)$ and $y = v - aw$, with $w \in V$ as in ***(a)***; then

$\lambda(y) = \lambda(v) - a \lambda(w) = \lambda(v) - \lambda(v) \cdot 1 = 0; \tag 7$

thus

$y \in \ker \lambda, \tag 8$

and

$v = aw + y = \lambda(v) w + y; \tag 9$

For ***(c)***, if $a_1, a_2 \in F$, $y_1, y_2 \in \ker \lambda \subset V$, and

$a_1 w + y_1 = v = a_2 w + y_2, \tag{10}$

then

$(a_1 - a_2)w = y_2 - y_1 \in \ker \lambda; \tag{11}$

so that

$a_1 - a_2 = (a_1 - a_2) \lambda(w) = \lambda((a_1 - a_2)w) = \lambda(y_2 - y_1) = 0; \tag{12}$

thus $a_1 = a_2$ from which (10) yields $y_1 = y_2$.  ***End:  Proof of Smallish Lemma.***

We may apply the ***Smallish Lemma*** to the present situation as follows: if $f = 0$, take $c = 0$ and we are done.  If $f \ne 0$, by ***Smallish*** there exists $w \in V$ with $f(w) = 1$; since for any $v \in V$,

$v = f(v)w + y, \; y \in \ker f = \ker g, \tag{13}$

$g(v) = g(f(v)w + y) = f(v)g(w) + g(y) = f(v)g(w) = g(w)f(v); \tag{14}$

now taking $c = g(w)$ we are done!

Comment: Great Work! +1 for you

Comment: Thank you, sir!  Cheers!